# Change number values higher than 200000 in notepad++

Tags: numbers, notepad++

How can I change about ~40000 values, using regex(?) higher than 200000?

Fe. Search for value > 200000, replace for: 200000 - 123456.

I have no idea, if it's possible in the Notepad++, or I have to use some other methods like PHP?

Comment: Can you describe what exactly you're trying to do? I don't understand the question.

Comment: With PHP you can do everything.

Comment: @sarnold I have no idea exactly what you don't understand.

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev Yep, I know. :)

Comment: This question is very unclear. Please try to restate the problem more clearly. For example: I presume "Fe." means For Example? Then why not type it out. The middle line makes no sense at all. It's clear you;re trying to manipulate some numbers with a regex, but I couldn't tell you what outcome you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many tools to do that, one of them is perl:

```
perl -pi -e 's,(\d+), ($1 < 200000) ? $1 : ($1 - 123456) ,ge' yourfile
```

Sample:

```
fge@erwin ~ $ perl -pe 's,(\d+), ($1 < 200000) ? $1 : ($1 - 123456) ,ge'
I have 3 apples and 290000 oranges   # input                                                                          
I have 3 apples and 166544 oranges   # output
```

If you have cygwin installed and perl, you are set.